# rewrite file extensions to a php file in a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm currently coding an API via PHP and now i want to rewrite some urls

`/apiname.json` to `/apiname/json.php`
`/apiname.xml` to `/apiname/xml.php`

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^apiname\.json$ apiname/json.php
RewriteRule ^apiname\.xml$ apiname/xml.php
```